# Why does phpinfo() in webpage show version 5.6, but php -v from command line shows 7.3?

Tags: php, macos, apache

Have read previous answers and understand that I must have two versions installed, but cannot locate where the 5.6 could be.  I changed /etc/bin/php to point to the version 7.3 I installed using brew.  I updated the /etc/apache2/httpd.conf to use php@7.3.  I restarted the server to be sure it would start apache reading from the httpd.conf.  Yet, when I run phpinfo from the webpage, It starts with 5.6 and does not include the http.conf info about the server administrator, yet it says it's using http.conf.  For some reason sudo apachectl restart will not work saying that the port is already in use.  I removed the /usr/local/php5 link ( renamed it to php5.bak ), so that it would not be used.

What other things should I look at?

Comment: You need to kill MacOS Apache, it likely starts with the system.

Comment: I'm running OS X Server on El Capitan.  I find that I cannot kill the Web server using any of these commands.  There are dozens of httpd running. I edit httpd.conf and restart computer, but edits do not show up.  The server version seems to be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a "partial" answer.  I am running Mac OS X 10.12.6 on a mac-mini as a web server.  The location of the configuration file for apache is:

```
/Library/Server/web/config/apache2/httpd_server_app.conf
```

Thus all of the /etc/apache2/httpd.conf and other suggestions, while they work fine on many unix and even OS X ( non-server ) where one has used brew to install, they don't work here.  I made some changes in the above file and verified that AFTER going to the Server app, selecting WebSites in the services menu, and clicking toggling the ON/OFF button to off, then back to on, the server is restarted.  All of the attempts using different apache2ctl restart, etc. do not work.

I am still somewhat puzzled that I don't see the server administrator that I enter showing up in the phpinfo.php display, but some other changes did.

My next quest, and suggestions are welcome, is how to change the http_server_app.conf file so that instead of php5, it will use my php7 that is available from the command line.  The attempt to change:

```
LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
#LoadModule php7_module libexec/apache2/libphp7.so
```

did not work as libphp7.so could not be located.  I'm now looking for it.  At one point in the conference file, I find:

```
<IfModule php5_module>
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
    AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
    <IfModule dir_module>
        DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Will I need to have one like this for php7_module, once I find it and use it above?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `php -v` command you use `php-cli` which can be diffrent version.
Also if you have multiple versions installed you may want disable apache module for old one.

```
sudo a2dismod php5 // disable php5.6
sudo a2enmod php7.3 // enable php7.3
```

Comment: @JohnWooten you can try edit apache config file, `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` or `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` and add module manualy `LoadModule php7_module modules/mod_php.so` but i dont know osx, to be honest.

Comment: As below, these files do not appear to control apache or at least php on OS X Server.  I'm trying to find where the actual apache server and configuration are located on OS X Server.

Answer (score 0):

There can be many different things that are causing it but I'm betting on MacOS Apache that's installed with the system. Try killing it from the startup:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist
```

Comment: This command has no effect.  I suspect that on OS X Server version, the control for the apache server lies elsewhere.  I'm trying to find out where!

Comment: Using the Server apps Wen Sites tab and sliding the ‘switch’ to off does work.